# How to add label on slick-grid-menu-item filter with checkbox for null/empty as (Blank)

Tags: javascript, java, html, slickgrid

I have one UI application to display static as well as business information. I have used slick grid to show all business data in tabular/grid structure by using all built-in properties of slick grid. I have used Sorting property to sort data in ascending/descending order on each column.

But I have a condition that if data is **not** available in any of the column then slick grid sorting option should show `Blank` option with check box like `Select All`. By default it is showing only a empty check box without any title.

[image: this is the snapshot of column where data is not available and i want to show a label beside checkbox]